# is there a way to convert automatically images files to odt format in linux terminal?

Tags: terminal, conversion, odt

is there a way to convert automatically images files to odt format in linux terminal?

I have eg. 100 jpg or 100 png image files. It may take much time to insert them one by one.

I have found many tools/converters for online image-to-odt, or in windows but not a terminal command in linux.

Do you know any?

Comment: Do you want to add all the images in one document?

Comment: `ODT`? As in `OpenDocument Text File`? If so then  you are NOT converting anything, you are merely importing it. Take a jpg, import it into a clean ODT file, then unzip that file. You will see an entry under `Pictures` with a hashed name. That entry is exactly what you initially imported. It's a jpg file, it's the same size as the original jpg, it's the exact same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps. First, convert all images to `.pdf` format using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php):

```
magick *.{png,jpg} output.pdf
```

Then there are a bunch of options to convert to `.odt`, e.g.:

- use [pdf2odt](https://github.com/gutschke/pdf2odt): `pdf2odt output.pdf output.odt` (EDIT: apparently this can convert images directly to `.odt` too, but not sure if it supports multiple)
- use [AbiWord](https://www.abisource.com/): `abiword --to=odt output.pdf`